# JQuery Datatables pagination in a Spring MVC & JSP webapp

Tags: jquery, jsp, datatables

I'm using Datatables JQuery plugin, by simply populating a `<table>` using JSTL's forearch.

I want to add server side paging capabilities to the table. I got the service methods ready for pagination using *maxResults* and *page*.

The table's cells are pretty customized with buttons, dropdowns & events inside cells hence I don't think I can use directly **"sAjaxSource"**(Can I?)

I was thinking to catch pagination change events of datatable and on each change make an ajax request with currentPage and maxResults...but this does not seem directly supported, there's no such event as *pageChanged* or smth.

How would you handle my situation? 
Thanks